# How to make a row number configurable in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to make the row number configurable in my macro, but my attempt in the below VBA code does not work:

**My Attempt:**

Assume that cell P2 = 3 in Sheet1 of the same workbook.

**Sheet2 VBA code:**

```
`Sub Test()
     DesiredRowNum= Sheet1!:P2
     Range("A2").Value= "= 1"
     Range("A3:A" & DesiredRowNum).Formula = "= $A2+1"
End Sub`
```

The desired output is that A2 increments by 1 for the number of rows specified by cell P2 in sheet1.

**EX1:**
If P2 = 3in sheet1, the output should be the below in sheet2:

1,

2,

3

**EX2:**
If P2 = 5 in sheet1, the output should be the below in sheet2:

1,

2,

3,

4,

5

Comment: Line 3 should be: Range("A2").Value= "1"

Comment: Then just [edit] your question.

Comment: Does `DesiredRowNum= Sheet1!:P2` work? You don't need to do `DesiredRowNum= Range("Sheet1!:P2").value`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using formulas, why not just use `ROW`?

```
Sub Test()
     Dim DesiredRowNum as Long
     DesiredRowNum= Sheet1.Range("P2").Value

     Range("A2:A" & DesiredRowNum + 1).Formula = "=ROW()-1"
End Sub`
```